# SQL Server - Does @@RowCount automatically commit transaction?

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I'm reviewing a developer's script to delete all data from a large table that is older than a specified date.

```
SET @R = 1;
WHILE @R > 0
    BEGIN
        ----Begin Transaction
        DELETE TOP (100000) FROM
        TBL_MYTABLE
        WHERE dateCreated < @DELETEDATE;

        ----Commit Transaction;
        SET @R = @@ROWCOUNT;

    END;
```

One thing that stood out to me is that he is checking the value of @@ROWCOUNT without doing anything with the @R variable.  Does that statement automatically commit the transaction?  Or would the entire WHILE loop have to complete first?

EDIT: As a followup question, how would I determine if each iteration of the loop is committing, or if it is waiting until the end?

Comment: Of course it doesn't commit a transaction. The way you commit a transaction is COMMIT TRANSACTION. If checking the row count variable auto committed a transaction that would criminally horrible design.

Comment: They do use the @R variable, in each iteration of the loop. They are deleting in batches (of 100K) here. You can always print @R at the bottom of the loop. It will be 100K each time, until the last iterations

Comment: Basically "while stuff got deleted, keep trying to delete", setting `@R = 1` just ensures that it tries the delete at least once

Comment: And, of course, with autocommit transactions, if there's no explicit transaction management here, the `DELETE` itself committed the transaction.

Comment: Also, in this code there is no explicit transaction. There is a comment about starting one, but nothing in the actual code.

Comment: My guess is that someone put a begin/end in when they wrote it and just commented it out at some point.

Comment: DShih is correct - the short answer is no. The explanation is not particularly helpful. You confuse 2 separate but related issues. A transaction is started, managed, and ended with specific statements. No other statement - delete included - will commit a transaction. Transaction management is a big topic; search if you need to understand more. The reason there is no transaction handling in this code is due to the goal behind the batch-delete logic. (cont)

Comment: Without an explicit transaction, each delete statement will be executed within a implicit transaction; rows will be deleted and committed or an error will be generated and the deleted rows rolled back **for each delete statement execution**. Why is this done. Because deleting very large numbers of rows can "blow up the transaction log". To avoid that error, one does batches of smaller deletes. Do you see a potential problem here? You should. What happens if the last delete executed generates an error? (cont)

Comment: Since each prior delete was effectively commited when the statement completed successfully, you cannot "roll back" all of those deletions. So how do you recover from a failure. Again - a big topic that you can search.

Comment: All of that is a more than bit simplistic but should give you the general idea. The developer is deleting lots of rows in an appropriate manner. It is your (apparently) responsibility to come up with a recovery plan in case something goes wrong. As an aside - why did you not have this discussion with the developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No it doesn't. because there isn't `COMMIT TRANSACTION` keyword

The sample is batch delete data.

Here is a sample we can see I set a `BREAK;` when `T` count amount smaller than or equal to 2.

When it exits from the loop we select the data from `T`, we can see only two rows.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    i int

);
INSERT INTO T values (1);
INSERT INTO T values (2);
INSERT INTO T values (3);
INSERT INTO T values (4);
INSERT INTO T values (5);

DECLARE @R INT = 1
SET @R = 1;
WHILE @R > 0
    BEGIN

        DELETE TOP (1) 
        FROM T


        SET @R = @@ROWCOUNT;

        IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T)<= 2)
          BREAK;

END;

SELECT * FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8647496befa6921bafd45f296f163816)

Comment: Do you mean that the DELETE statement is committing the changes on each run of the loop?

Comment: When you call the `DELETE` statement it will execute the `DELETE` action.